# What does this command do: top -bHn 1 -u mail?

Tags: 14.04, top

```
top -bHn 1 -u mail
```

I've read through the man pages and there seems to be some stuff there that is not included in them. Pointing me to additional documentation would be helpful too. In particular, I'm not sure what the 1 is doing or mail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man top`

```
   -b : Batch mode operation
        Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending
        output from top to other programs or  to  a  file.   In  this
        mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
        limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option  or  until
        killed.

   -H : Threads toggle
        Starts top with the last remembered 'H' state reversed.  When
        this  toggle is On, all individual threads will be displayed.
        Otherwise, top displays a  summation  of  all  threads  in  a
        process.

   -n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies  the  maximum  number of iterations, or frames, top
        should produce before ending.

   -u : Monitor by user as:  -u somebody
        Monitor only processes with an effective  UID  or  user  name
        matching that given.
```

So it means operate in batch mode (`-b`), toggle thread display (`-H`), for a single iteration (`-n 1`), showing only processes belonging to user `mail` (`-u mail`) : basically an one-time snapshot of the current threads belonging to `mail`, more or less equivalent to `ps -Lfu mail`